# Whats wrong with this ssh-keygen command?

Tags: powershell, ssh, command-line-arguments, openssh, ssh-keygen

I'm using `ssh-keygen` on Windows to create a fresh key pair of SSH keys.
But if I execute the command I get the following error:

**Too many arguments.**

Command:
`ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f ~/.ssh/id_local -H ~/.ssh/known_hosts_local -C "Local Hosts"`

I wonder if anyone out there encountered this before or knows what's wrong with my set of command arguments.

CodingSheep

Comment: I'd say that `ssh-keygen -?` enumerates valid syntax patterns; yours one doesn't match any…

Answer (score 0):

The -H option is supposed to optionnally use a known hosts file with `-f`

```
-H [-f known_hosts_file]
```

So you should use:

```
-H -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts_local 
   ^^^
```

I just tested it on Windows 10, an it does work.
`-H` alone would update the default `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.